# How to define a number as missing value when set up a array in R

Tags: r

I want to set up an array in R with a specific number as the missing value.
I want to set up this array *directly*, just one step.

In the following code, I want 15 to be a missing value. 
array(1:45,dim=c(3,3,5),***NA=15***) 
Here NA=15 is a fake parameter imagined by me, I can realize this method in other languages.

Does R have a similar parameter or function like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number you want in advance you could set it as NA directly in the array.

```
array(c(1:14, NA, 16:45), dim = c(3,3,5))
```

If that doesn't do it for you, you could define your own function:

```
array2 <- function(data, dim, na.num){
   my_array <- array(data = data, dim = dim)
   my_array[my_array == na.num] <- NA
   return(my_array)
}

array2(1:45, dim = c(3,3,5), na.num = 15)
```

**EDIT**

You could also use this:

```
array(gsub(15, NA, 1:45), dim = c(3,3,5))
```

The `gsub` substitutes an NA for any instance of 15 within 1:45 and then makes your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it afterward.

```
test= array(sample(1:10,1000,replace = T),dim = c(10,10,10))
test[test==5] <- NA
```

If you are reading data from csv files, there is a parameter `na.strings`you can set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I know I can set it afterward.
But I want to realize it directly, not afterward. Because this array will be used to receive values generated by my code.
Maybe there is no functionality like this.

Comment: I also did some searching on how to set it in advance. But there were no relevant answers. So it's possible that there is no such functionality. The closest I can get is the `na_string` thing in reading files.

Comment: Ok, I can use your method to realize my intention indirectly. 
Thanks again.